# How can I derive relative translation and rotation from two extrinsic camera matrices?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, perspectivecamera

I have two sets of data associated with a video sequence. One contains relative rotation and translation data generated using one algorithm. The other is comprised of ground-truth extrinsic matrices associated with each frame.

I would like to compare the data-sets to determine the disparity between them. My question is, how can I derive the relative translation and rotation from the two extrinsic camera matrices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `camera1` pose `P1 = [R1|T1]` and `camera2` pose `P2 = [R2|T2]` then `P1to2 = P2 * P1^-1`.

Intuitively, imagine a simple case in which both cameras have translation zero, `camera1` has rotation on X axis +30 degrees and `camera2` rotation on X axis of +60 degrees.

```
P1 = [R1|0] P2 = [R2|0]
```

So they both differ of a +30 degrees rotation on the X axis:

```
P1to2 = P2 * P1^-1 = [R2|0] * [R1|0]^-1 = [R2|0] * [R1^1|0]

R2 * R1^1 = 60 - 30 on X = rotation of +30 degrees on X
```

Comment: Can you confirm that the pose P = N^-1, where N is the extrinsic matrix?

Comment: How to calculate the relative translation then?

Comment: @aledalgrande What would be the relative rotation when cameras don't have zero translation? On what would we apply the inverse translation to get the above case of zero translation?

Answer (score 0):

The extrinsic matrix is comprised of the rotation matrix 3x3 and the translation vector 3x1.

So, M 3x4, is simply a concatenation of the two [R t].  Unless I misunderstand your question, getting the rotation and translation is trivial.

Comment: R and t are the rotation and translation of the world with respect to the camera. Obtaining their world coordinate equivalents isn't difficult either. What I'm looking for is the delta between two frames, given their extrinsic matrices. For example, the translation between frame 1 and frame 2.

Comment: Do you mean transformation between pixel coordinates in frame 1 and 2 ?